# A practical way to check whether a module is periodic

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, computer-algebra, gap

A module $M$ over a finite dimensional selfinjective algebra $A$ over a field $K$ is called periodic if $M \cong \Omega^n(M)$ for some $n \geq 1$. We assume here that $M$ is simple and that A is a quiver algebra (which only contains -1 or +1 in its relations if that helps or is needed).

In practise, I am mainly interested when $A$ is the trivial extension of an incidence algebra (or more genally an acyclic Schurian quiver algebra), which is a very nice class of algebras.

(Thanks to Jeremy Rickard for providing a counterexample to the original question where M was just indecomposable)

> Question: Is there a finite test to check whether a given simple module is not periodic?

I believe the following should have a positive answer:

> Question 2: Does there exists a number $s(A)$ that just depends on the dimension of $A$ such that if $\Omega^i(M)$ is not isomorphic to $M$ for $i=1,...,s(A)$ then $M$ is not periodic?

A related question is the following:

> Question 3: Does there exists a number $d(A)$ that just depends on the dimension of $A$ such that if $\Omega^n(M)>d(A)$ for some $n \geq 1$, then $M$ is not periodic?

It seems to me that one might choose $s(A)$ and $d(A)$ to be something like $2dim(A)+30$, but I have no good attempt to prove something like this.

Any practical reference/advice one might use to show that a given module is not periodic is also welcome (even in special cases such as symmetric algebras etc.).

Comment: Out of curiosity: where does the number $30$ come from?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda There is a result by Bongartz that for quiver algebra $A$ one has that $A$ is representation-infinite when there is an indecomposable module of dimension at least $max(2dim(A),30)$. 30 also nearly the highest dimension of an indecomposable $E_8$-modules. So it is more or less nothing but an obscure guess. Also I did alot of tests and the bound was good in all examples.

Comment: If you don't insist that $M$ should be simple, then for Question 2, can't you take $A=k\langle x,y\rangle/(x^2,xy-syx,y^2)$ and $M=A/(x-y)A$ for a class of examples with $\dim(A)=4$ and $\dim(M)=2$, where the period of $M$ can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $s$ to be a root of unity with sufficiently large order?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Right, I forgot about that example. I actually just did tests for simpels and when the algebra is defined such that the relations contain only 1 or -1. I restricted the question to simple modules for now.